# mocking a class that has a private constructor?

Tags: java, scala, mocking, mockito, scalatest

I need to mock a java class that has a private constructor and only a static create method.

What would be the typical solution in that kind of situation.

With or without a framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerMock to mock static methods https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage, so you would mock the static create method and return whatever you want. It's easier if the static method returns an interface rather than a class so you can return your own mock implementation of it.

Comment: I was reading here and there, and what came out as a solution is to create a wrapper around the class. The rational behind it being, don't mock type that you don't own. Indeed, the type come from a lib. I do not own it. However, i don't like the idea of wrapping things. I think it can be costly. But at least i would mock my type and and verify the call.

Comment: Yes, if you don't own it, that is one solution. Wrapping it protects consumers of your class from dealing with implementation details of the 3rd party library. It's a balance though - you can go crazy if you try to wrap everything.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !!! In the current the thing is just a pain, so wrapping is just better. But yeah whenever i can avoid wrapping i would go for not wrapping.